# Java classes looks different (.java) when I imported a Spring Boot project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I imported a Spring Boot project from GitLab in IntelliJ IDEA. And the classes look different in the project, they have this form: `ApiDemo.java`, `ApiDevice.java`. All the classes have this form. The problem is that I cannot run the unit tests, there is no button to run the unit tests. And I need to run these tests. How can I do in this situation? In other projects classes looks like this: `TransDemo`, `TransApi` and they have a blue circle with "c" in the middle.

Comment: You did the import wrong. Read a guide on how to import. We can't help, since we don't know what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Explorer (if you use Windows OS, or something like this in Linux, macOS). Delete metadata what generated by IntelliJ IDEA IDE (`*.iml` file , metadata directory), then reimport project.